# HTML logo not responsive

Tags: html, css

I am making a website.  In its footer I have a logo. It's on the right place but when I visit the site with mobile, the logo is on the wrong position.

It was working before and now it is not. I can't figure out why.  Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<footer class="page-foot bg-dark">
    <section class="footer-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="rd-navbar-brand pull-lg-left"><a href="index.html" 
class="brand-name">
<img src="logo1.png" style="width: 35%" width="120px">               
</div>
        <div style="text-align: left;">
        <ul class="list-inline list-inline-mod-1 visible-md-inline-block 
visible-lg-inline-block pull-sm-right">
          <li><a href="meadows.html">Rolling Meadows</a></li>
          <li><a href="heights.html">Attorney Arlington Heights</a></li>
          <li><a href="palatine.html">Lawyer Palatine </a></li>
          <li><a href="mount.html">Attorney Mount Prospect</a></li>
          <li><a href="des.html">Lawyer Des Plaines</a></li>
          <li><a href="scha.html">Attorney Schaumburg</a></li>
          <li><a href="hoff.html">Hoffman Estates</a></li>
          <li><a href="elk.html">Attorney Elk Grove Village</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </footer>
```

**CSS** It's specifying the position for the logo

```
.page-foot .rd-navbar-brand {
   margin-bottom: -4%;
   margin-left: -18%;
}
```

I am new in `CSS` and `HTML`, could you explain why this happens?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? It's not displaying the logo? Or the logo is stretched, distorted, etc.?

Comment: Its not on right place, its away from footer

Comment: How far off is it? Like top of the screen or just moved over some?

Comment: @MartinĎurický Think you could link the website in question?

Comment: Link is in the description. Its not far its just little lower and more left

Comment: @A.Williams link re-added (I removed it by accident while editing)

Comment: Wait! the link just got flagged as phishing by my firewall (can anyone verify?) else I'll remove the link

Comment: There is no ssl, maybe because of it?

Comment: Nope! that's not it.

Comment: I dont know then, its just on free hosting, i am testing one template... What can cause that problem?

Comment: @ochi May be a false positive, I'm not getting anything

Comment: @A.Williams ok, thx - I'll flag it as a false-positive on my end

Comment: So do you know guys what is causig that problem with logo in footer?

Comment: What's the intended behavior? https://i.imgur.com/Ct5YDSA.png Do you just want the logo moved up slightly, closing that gap?

Comment: Yes i want it to be in that footer and more in the center

Comment: Gonna make a leap here and guess you're using a website builder, are there any centering tools you can use in the mobile-view, or failing that, can you manually set the padding/margin on the logo/logo container?

Comment: No i am not using website builder, i am just editing code of that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.page-foot .rd-navbar-brand has negative margins on it - take those off and it should go back to the right spot! Added some bottom padding so the logo has equal padding on the top/bottom.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .page-foot .rd-navbar-brand{
    margin: 0 0 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: But if i remove that - its on right place on mobile version but on pc its on wrong

Comment: Add a media query resetting the margin, editing above with an example

Comment: Oh and one more question - how to deal with this?  Check footer for example on resolution of iPad. http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//testwebsites.9e.cz/index.html&w=1024&h=768&a=22&s=1

Comment: Just bump the max-width part from 767 to 992, which is when tablet seems to kick in!